# How to edit Title in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, object, fullcalendar, servicenow

I'm trying to use the fullcalendar library in ServiceNow and everything seems to be working fine, but there's something weird going on with the Title:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid the undefinedundefined by making changes to the Title object?  My current code is pretty simple:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
})
```

Comment: What version of Fullcalendar, momentjs, jquery being used? Unable to replicate @ https://jsfiddle.net/996frp04/ with jquery 3.2.1, momentjs 2.18.1, fullcalendar 3.4.0 with above code snippet.

Comment: i'm using fullcalendar 3.4.0, jquery 3.2.1, and momentjs 2.17.1

Comment: should i use the 2.18.1 version of moment?  also does it matter if i use the min.js file instead of the js?

Comment: Using minified vs original of those libraries shouldn't cause a difference in output. I swapped out moment.js 2.18.1 to 2.17.1 to match your setup, still doesn't replicate @ https://jsfiddle.net/996frp04/1/ - is there anything else going on in the page that isn't in the above snippet?

Comment: Did you find out what was causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used different version of full calendar css and js file.
in this it works fine. please check your file version used. i hope it should be helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
        })

    });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
```